# Application reloads from the launch activity when icon clicked in some devices?

Tags: applications

Our application relaunches from the launch activity on some devices when the icon is clicked in the launcher, while on others it resumes its current state when clicked in launcher.  The application uniformly resumes its current state when resumed from the application history.

The behavior is different even in different phones that are the same running the same OS i.e. two Galaxy Note 2's both running 4.1.2.

Comment: So what's the question? Are you looking just for a reason behind this, or a solution/fix to prevent this non-uniform behavior?

Comment: My guess is that your application is being terminated on one device, while staying in memory on the other.  This is a common scenario since Android's own memory management will free up memory by terminating apps when necessary.

Comment: @filoxo A reason, and to know if I need to fix it.

Comment: @Chahk I doubt it.  Again I can always pull it back up from the history list.  If it was out of memory *where* I launch it from shouldn't have an impact.